# How could i revert the guild vanity url?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I own a 10k discord server and receantly our server vainty was stolen, so i'm working on something to revert the vainty back to whatever it was last.

My code is

```
async def on_guild_update(before, after):
    guild = after
        if after.name == before.name:
             return
        elif after.name != before.name:
            bname = before.name
            await guild.edit(name=bname)
        elif after.vanity_code != before.vanity_code:
            code = before.vanity_code
            await guild.edit(vanity_code=code)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

But it doesn't work, I don't even get an error. And suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: You didn't even placed the try, and it must be a syntax error dude.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to work with the vanity url and here's what I found:

if I do

```
await guild.edit(vanity_code=code)
```

it works, but if I try to do

```
before_code = ctx.guild.vanity_code
```

it gives me error

```
'Guild' object has no attribute 'vanity_code'
```

I don't know why that happens but I hope that will help you at least a bit :)